Cakephp 4 : How I will get auth information in middleware?
I have created a middleware called
CompanyMiddleware
And I have it in my application.php middleware like below
public function middleware(MiddlewareQueue $middlewareQueue): MiddlewareQueue
{

        $middlewareQueue
            ->add(new ErrorHandlerMiddleware(Configure::read('Error')))
            ->add(new AssetMiddleware([
                'cacheTime' => Configure::read('Asset.cacheTime'),
            ]))
            ->add(new RoutingMiddleware($this))
            ->add(new BodyParserMiddleware())
            ->add(new CsrfProtectionMiddleware([
                'httponly' => true,
            ]))
            ->add(new AuthenticationMiddleware($this))
            ->add(new CompanyMiddleware($this));

        return $middlewareQueue;
}

I'm using cakephp authentication plugin. I have tried to fetch authentication information using getIdentity(). but getting null.
This is my CompanyMiddleware
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Middleware;

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Server\MiddlewareInterface;
use Psr\Http\Server\RequestHandlerInterface;
use Authentication\AuthenticationServiceInterface;

/**
 * Company middleware
 */
class CompanyMiddleware implements MiddlewareInterface
{

    public function process(ServerRequestInterface $request, RequestHandlerInterface $handler): ResponseInterface
    {

        $result = $this->authenticationService->getIdentity($request);

        dd($result);
        return $handler->handle($request);
    }
}

Question is how I will get Authentication information/data in CompanyMiddleware ?

First you need to asses your use-case, specifically the type of authentication. With form authentication for example, there will of course be requests with no authentication credentials supplied, eg when the login form is being requested, and you'd need to account for that accordingly. Generally, if valid authentication credentials have been provided, the service should have the details. getResult() on the service could also give you a hint.

Thank you @ndm
I got user info by dd( $request->getAttribute('identity')->get('email') );
I have solved it after read https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/identity-object.html
